# How to stream trades from Binance web socket API in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I am trying to use the Binance API to get the latest trades on a crypto-currency pair. Here is the endpoint to the API, say for BTC/USDT: **wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/btcusdt@trade**

I tested this API on https://www.websocket.org/echo.html, and was successful in getting a continuous stream of new trades.

How do I use this API in Node.js to continuously output the trades on the console? Is there any specific library or package you recommend?

Comment: Open a websocket and listen to it.

Answer (score 30):

I feel kind of stupid for not finding this package earlier. I used [ws](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws) to accomplish the task. Below are the lines of code I typed:

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');

const ws = new WebSocket('wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/btcusdt@trade');

ws.on('message', function incoming(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: additional, data is a json as string, we need use JSON.parse or some similar library

Answer (score 10):

And this is how to stream Futures trades from `Binance` today:

```
import {WebSocket} from 'ws';

const coin = 'btcusdt';

const ws = new WebSocket(`wss://fstream.binance.com/ws/${coin}@trade`);

ws.on('message', (data?: string) => {
    if (data) {
        const trade = JSON.parse(data); // parsing a single-trade record
        console.log(trade);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

- for multiple trades

const ws = new WebSocket('wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/btcusdt@trade/bnbusdt@trade');

Comment: but how to get my trades with this websocket link without authentification (api_key and secret_key)???

Answer (score -1):

Combined streams are accessed at /stream?streams=//

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).